# macOS - Bash commands not working as needs to be

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, path

First of all, the problems:

- I'm not able to use both exported bash commands and default system bash commands at the same time
- Some of the exported paths working on terminal but some of them not

Things I did:

I was adding exports to my .bash_profile but I got the problems, then I searched for solutions. Tried a couple of things. I'm not sure if I did something wrong or what.

- Changed: Terminal -> Preferences -> Shells open with, then reverted to default
- Deleted .bashrc and .bash_profile files then reverted them to the first state
- Corrected the $PATH directory, did everything in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/498356

If I restart the terminal, default bash commands working but if I source the .bash_profile or .bashrc then some of the exports working some of not and the default bash command not working(e.g. open command not working).

How can I manage to get it to work simultaneously while all my additional bash commands working?

My .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/user/Library/Android/ndk-build:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:~/Flutter/flutter/bin
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
```

Sorry, I'm searching for hours and there too many different kinds of questions, solutions, suggestions and it's hard to figure out what should I do exactly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `\` in front of `$PATH` in the last line and start a new shell

Comment: Thanks! Now everything is working, you saved my day!
Such a mini mistake, I copied that line from the official website :/

Comment: @mathronaut Do you mean the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line)? if so, the escape (backslash) is there in the docs because it's part of a here-document that's being appended to ~/.bash_profile, and the backslash will be removed as part of the here-document processing (it's needed to keep `$PATH` from expanding prematurely). There's a note that "You should remove the leading slash if you want to run the export command directly in a terminal", but it doesn't point out that the same thing applies if you're editing the file directly.

Comment: @mathronaut P.s. if this solved your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes it's solved my problem, thanks for all your help and great explanations!